# Trigger recursion error

Tags: apex, trigger, case, standard-objects, recursion

I have set up my Case trigger with a single trigger and separate methods class to handle the activities.

I have added a Recursion Handler class to try and prevent the recursion happening, but this does not seem to be working properly at the moment, as when I manually edit a class it causes the error message to be displayed:

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger WSC_CaseTrigger caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: WSC_CaseTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate
>   caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row
>   0 with id 5005E000000uUQHQA2; first error:
>   SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 5005E000000uUQH) is
>   currently in trigger WSC_CaseTrigger, therefore it cannot recursively
>   update itself: []: Class.WSC_Case_Trigger_Methods.setCaseLOS: line
>   154, column 1

I am getting this error whether I put the call to the recursion handler around the specific method call that has the error linked to it or the entire trigger body of code.

**Recursion Handler**

```
    public class RecursiveTriggerHandler {
    public Static Boolean isFirstTime = true;

}
```

**Trigger code**

```
if (RecursiveTriggerHandler.isFirstTime) {
       RecursiveTriggerHandler.isFirstTime = false;
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate) {
        List<Case> updateList = new List<Case>();


        for(Case caseObj : Trigger.New){
            if(caseObj.Status != 'New' && caseObj.Materially_Complete_Date__c != Null) {
                // call method in Case methods to keep case trigger class simple.
                updateList.add(new Case(id =caseObj.Id));

            }
            system.debug('No of cases to update'+updateList.size());
            WSC_Case_Trigger_Methods.setCaseLOS(updateList);
            }  

        }
    }
```

**Relevant method of Trigger handler that is causing the exception**

```
public static void setCaseLOS(List<Case>lstUpdate){
    WSC_Date_Functions date_Functions = new WSC_Date_Functions();
    System.debug('Start LOS updates');

     if(lstUpdate.size()>0){
         Integer daysBetween;
         Id MeteringRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Metering').getRecordTypeId();
         //Id MDDRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Maximum_Daily_Demand').getRecordTypeId();
        System.debug('updating case dates');
         for(case updates : lstUpdate) {
             if(updates.Market_Data_Accepted__c!=Null&&updates.Proposed_Date_to_Update_MO__c!=Null){                    

                updates.Market_Data_Response_Day__c = Date_Functions.Working_Days_Between(updates.Proposed_Date_to_Update_MO__c, updates.Market_Data_Accepted__c) ;
             }
             if(updates.Materially_Complete_Date__c != Null && updates.RecordTypeId==MeteringRecordType){
                 if(updates.Process_Reference__c=='B1'&&updates.Actual_Date_of_Exchange__c!=Null) {
                     daysBetween =  Date_Functions.Working_Days_Between(updates.Date_Quotation_Approved__c, updates.Actual_Install_Date__c); 
                     updates.Operational_Response_Days__c = daysBetween;
                     System.assert(daysBetween!=Null);
                     System.debug('Days between'+daysBetween);
                 }

             }

         }
       //update the cases
       update lstUpdate;

   }
```

Comment: Is that before update or after update trigger? Long story short, you can not execute update on same object in after update trigger which is in trigger

Comment: The trigger has both before and after update methods in it, but looking at the best practices there should be one trigger per object so hard to avoid that - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices

Comment: well, be sure that your logic fire only once. In case if that is before trigger -- you do not need to execute update on record in trigger itself. if that is after -- you need to construct new sObject and update it (With id of existing one) or do job async (future/queueable)

Comment: reread your code --> it is before, so remove update statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple solution is to follow the `Apex Developer Guide` recommendations on **[`Triggers`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)**. Field updates belong in a `before` trigger and do not require a separate update call. When applying field updates in this way, you do not even need a static flag to block recursion, because you will not cause `update` trigger re-entry.

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - Before triggers are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - After triggers are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

So a more appropriate pattern would be:

**Trigger**

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert, before update)
{
    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert)
        {
            CaseService.setSomeField(CaseService.applySomeFilter(trigger.new));
            // other methods
        }
        if (trigger.isUpdate)
        {
            CaseService.setSomeField(CaseService.applySomeFilter(trigger.new));
            // other methods
        }
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public static List<Case> applySomeFilter(List<Case> records)
{
    List<Case> filtered = new List<Case>();
    //filter logic
    return filtered;
}
public static void setSomeField(List<Case> filtered)
{
    for (Case record : filtered)
    {
        record.Some_Field__c = someValue;
    }
}
```